# how to make a newly created comment into a child/reply of another comment using acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The gems documentation says comment.move_to_child_of(parent_comment). Can anyone point to an example of how best to use this method (some code would be grateful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@comment.move_to_child_of(@parent)